# How to show image in full screen when click on image in chat box

Tags: html, css, image, screen

how to show image in full screen on screen when click on image in the chat box.

i tried when click on image it not opening in total screen image mot showing

like below we want

http://jsfiddle.net/YbMTg/666/

```js
$(document).on('click', '#im', function (){
 $(".popphoto").toggle(function()
   {
    $(this).animate({width: "400px"}, 'slow');},
        function()
        {$(this).animate({width: "120px"}, 'slow');
    });
 });
```

```html
<div class="right">
     <img class="popphoto" src="images\services.jpg" width="100%" height="100px">
 </div>
```

[image: Actual result]

[image: Expected result]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: There is a plugin called `lightbox`, which dims out the background and displays the images in full screen, just as you require. Read [here](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) for better understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$('#im').click(function(){
  $('#divLoading').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="right">
  <img  id="im" src="http://www.html-helper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/HTML.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
</div>


<div id="divLoading" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: fixed; right: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #ffffff; z-index: 30001; opacity: 1; filter: alpha(opacity=70);display:none" > 
    <p style="position: absolute; top: 20%; left: 20%; color: White;"> 
        <img  id="im" src="http://www.html-helper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/HTML.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
    </p> 
</div>
```

Comment: Alorika it working but it is looks like image open in another page we want to open in that page only. like we want like this but in that image is not open in full screen http://jsfiddle.net/YbMTg/666/

Comment: It is opened in the same page. I have just put an overlay on the whole body (with the help of div) and put the image inside the div.

Comment: i atteched the screen shot and modified the question pls once see it